# Archive Page Not Found on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I created a custom post type with a taxonomy defined, but I am having trouble getting an archive page to show up.

1. I get a 404 page not found. The individual post shows up but nothing on archives page.

functions php.

```
function create_post_type() {  
    register_post_type( 'my_properties',  
        array(  
            'labels' => array(  
                'name' => __( 'Commercial Properties' ),  
                'singular_name' => __( 'My Property' )  
            ),  
        'public' => true,  
        'menu_position' => 5,  
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Myproperties')  
        )  
    );  
}  

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' ); 

function property_taxonomy() {  
   register_taxonomy(  
    'properties',  
    'my_properties',  
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'label' => 'Category',  
        'query_var' => true,  
    )  
);  
}  

add_action( 'init', 'property_taxonomy' );
```

I have tried:

• Creating an **archive-my_properties.php** (should the page be named after the registration or the slug?
• Resaved permalinks
• Flushed Rewrite rules

Comment: Please separate ACF issue into a separate question (if it would be in-scope for WPSE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `'has_archive' => true` in the arguments array you pass to [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments). The default value is `false`, which means that WordPress does not generate an archive index for the post type.

Comment: good grief, tried everything except to see if the vcr was plugged in.